# Add quantity in ManyToMany fields in Djangp

Tags: python, django, django-models, client

I'm developing a CRM that controls and organizes sales in DJANGO. SO I have the class Sale (Venda) and the class Product. In the class Sale, I have the Many To Many fields referencing the Product class. My question is if is possible to add a field related to the quantity. I mean, a person can ask in a single sale to add multiple quantities of multiple products, right? Can I implement that in models.py?

My codes are:

```
Venda.models.py:

   class Product(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price           = models.DecimalField(null=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=100)
    cost            = models.DecimalField(null=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=100)
    stock           = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    materials       = models.ManyToManyField(to='producao.MateriaPrima')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    

    class Sale(models.Model):
        client      = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
        product     = models.ManyToManyField(Produto)
        plataform  = models.CharField(choices=PLATAFORMAS, null=True, max_length=1000)
        status      = models.CharField(choices=STATUS, null=True, max_length=1000)
        data_pedido = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, null=True, default=datetime.now)
        data_entrega= models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    
        paid        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        payment     = models.CharField(choices=PAGAMETOS, null=True, max_length=200)
        
        num_itens   = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
        total_price = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=100)
    
        profit = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, max_digits=100)
```

the last three items are calculated and filled automatically in signals.py

But the way this is implemented, the user can only add a single unit of each product in a Sale object. I want to know if there is a way to add multiple quantities of the same Product in this class Sale. And if it's possible, how can I implement it?

Thanks, comunity!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `through=…` model that acts like a junction table in between:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # …

class Sale(models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField(
        Product,
        through='ProductSale'
    )

class ProductSale(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Produto', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sale = models.ForeignKey('Sale', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=('product', 'sale'), name='once_per_product_sale')
        ]
```

Then you can for example add three times the same product to a sale with:

```
from decimal import Decimal

movie = Product.objects.get_or_create(name='movie', price=Decimal('14.25'))
sale = Product.objects.create()
ProductSale.objects.create(product=movie, sale=sale, quantity=3)
```

You can calculate the price for a `Sale` with:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

Sale.objects.aggregate(
    total=Sum(F('productsale__quantity')*F('product__price'))
)['total']
```